# Get result based on Row_number criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have tables three tables: `#T`, `#T1`, `#Maintable`, for which I'll attach the corresponding DDL.

```
Create table  #T ( id int , reason varchar (50));    

insert into #T Values (1,'Texas for live music');
insert into #T Values (1,'Texas for BBQ');
insert into #T Values (2,'Wisconsin for dairy products');
insert into #T Values (2,'Wisconsin for Rock');
insert into #T Values (2,'Wisconsin for Bird');
insert into #T Values (3,'North Carolina for Pepsi');
insert into #T Values (4,'Missouri for Forest');
insert into #T Values (5,'Oklohoma for cowboy');
insert into #T Values (5,'Oklohoma for Native Americans');
insert into #T Values (5,'Oklohoma for oil and gas');
   
Create table  #T1 ( id int , reason varchar (50));   

insert into #T1 Values (1,'Texas for live music,BBQ');
insert into #T1 Values (2,'Wisconsin for dairy products, rock,bird');
insert into #T1 Values (3,'North Carolina for Pepsi');
insert into #T1 Values (4,'Missouri for Forest');
insert into #T1 Values (5,'Oklohoma for Native Americans,oil and gas');

Create table #MainTable (id int, State varchar(20),Capital varchar(30),Governer varchar(30)); 

Insert into #Maintable values (1,'Texas','Austin','A');
Insert into #Maintable values (2,'Wisconsin','Madison','B');
Insert into #Maintable values (3,'North Carolina','Releigh','C');
Insert into #Maintable values (4,'Missouri','Jefferson City','D');
Insert into #Maintable values (5,'Oklohoma','Oklohoma city','E');
```

**Expected Output**

| ID | Reason | State | Capital | Governer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Texas for live music,BBQ | Texas | Austin | A |
| 2 | Wisconsin for dairy products, rock,bird | Wisconsin | Madison | B |
| 3 | North Carolina for Pepsi | North Carolina | Releigh | C |
| 4 | Missouri for Forest | Missouri | Jefferson City | D |
| 5 | Oklohoma for Native Americans,oil and gas | Oklohoma | Oklohoma city | E |

I have a couple of tables, based on the criteria I will be filtering records from table #T and joining with other tables to get more columns but with the help of cte, I am not able to filter. if first table #T has more than one Id then we will be using reason from another table #T1. If it has only one Id then we will be using Reason from Table #T and finally, we will join with #main table to get other records. I have added an image describing more. Help is much appreciated. All those temp tables we can test

And the scenario is:

- If reason appears more than once in #T table use #T1 table
- If reason appears only once in the #T table use #T only, this is the first table

Here's my coding attempt:

```
with cte as (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by id) rn 
    from #T 
)
select mt.id, state, capital, Governer,
       case when c.rn > 1 
            then #t1.reason 
            else c.reason 
       end as reason
from cte c 
join #t1           on c.id = #t1.id 
join #maintable mt on c.id = mt.id
```

I am getting more results, I was expecting only 5 records. I guess there is some issue in my row_number. Help is appreciated.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) *"It is not not letting me to add code"* It did but the problem is you basically formatted your *entire* question as code, which meant that by the time you tried to add the (markdown?) tables, you effectively had no content to your question. I've fixed the formatting issues (though there are plenty of other problems with your post), so you can now [edit] your question to add the data in a consumable format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first extract the ranking value from the table "*#T*" for each ID. Then you can use the `COALESCE` function in combination with `LEFT JOIN` operations to solve your problem:

```
WITH #T_ranked AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY reason) AS rn 
    FROM #T
)
SELECT m.id, 
       COALESCE(#T1.reason, #T_ranked.reason) AS Reason,
       m.State, 
       m.Capital, 
       m.Governer
FROM      #Maintable m
LEFT JOIN #T1 ON m.id = #T1.id
LEFT JOIN #T_ranked ON m.id = #T_ranked.id AND #T_ranked.rn = 1
```

The `LEFT JOIN` operations will make your ids in the "*MainTable*" be kept, while the `COALESCE` function will make the first non-null argument to be the value for the "*Reason*" new field, in the specific case it will check whether "*#T1.Reason*" is null, if it is then it will assign "*#T2.Reason*". Values from "*#T.Reason*" which have an existing correspondent in "*#T1.Reason*" will never be selected in this way.

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/LUhLETZt).

Comment: Hi I gues this will not work I am expecting as                      Expected Result    
ID Reason State Capital Governer
1 Texas for live music,BBQ Texas Austin A
2 Wisconsin for dairy products, rock,bird Wisconsin Madison B
3 North Carolina for Pepsi North Carolina Releigh C
4 Missouri for Forest Missouri Jefferson City D
5 Oklohoma for Native Americans,oil and gas Oklohoma Oklohoma city E

Comment: I guess you're getting more rows than expected due to the "1-to-n" relationship cardinality between "*MainTable*" and "*#T*" tables, try now with the updated query.

Comment: Update your post accordingly with your environment completely cleaned out for what concerns images, tables and final query, then I may help you. Currently I'm not understanding your problem as is.

Comment: Check the updated answer: play with the provided demo if you want. Does it work for you?